# How to show friendlist in Custom Arrowchat

Tags: php, chat

I am integrating the arrow chat trial. It is working fine for guest chat. But my requirement is chat within my friends only.

Then what type of changes to be done in `integration.php` file? `Config.php` is set as per documentation. But the notification is comes up **"you must register or login to use chat"**. Header and footer scripts and css files are already set.

I am testing with a `test.php` page and set a session for `userid`. But `integration.php` is not called. So I need include this page to my `test.php` page, then how I fix the issue?

### TEST.PHP

```
<?php session_start();
include_once "includes/integration.php";
$_SESSION['userid']='';

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />

 <title>test</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="arrowchat_css" media="all"    href="/development/newchat/external.php?type=css" charset="utf-8" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/development/newchat/includes/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/development/newchat/includes/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<form action="" method="post">
<input name="userid" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

 $_SESSION['userid']=$_POST['userid']; 
 $return=get_user_id();
 get_online_list($return,time());

 }

 ?>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/development/newchat/external.php?type=djs" charset="utf-8">   </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/development/newchat/external.php?type=js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```